# Swipe on a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code to swipe between the pages, my content is a simple image.

The problem is that i cant swipe over the image, only in a specify area between header and image.

But i want swipe to the next page over the image too.

how can i solved it? need help

My Code HTML5:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">                      
  <h1>2013</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <img src="imagens/HomePrincipal.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">                  
   <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">                     
  <a href="#p1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
        <h1>2013</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <img src="imagens/PrototipoAlternativo2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">              
     <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){    
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {    
        var nextpage = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;         
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){   
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {      
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;            
});
```

CSS master.css:

```
.gridContainer {
    width: 88.2%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.9%;
    padding-right: 0.9%;
    margin: auto;
}
#test img{position:absolute;z-index:-1}
```

boilerplate.css:

```
img { border: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; vertical-align: middle; }
```

and i use jquery.mobile.1.2.0.min.css

Comment: i have tested in dreamweaver cs6 and works, but if i open in a browser like firefox, chrome etc.  nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

(cant comment..) Maybe the images is laying on top of the div? a lower css z-index on the image then on the swipediv so that you can reach it?

Comment: and are you sure the swipediv stretches over the whole content you want to swipe?

Comment: yes.. because i can only swipe between the header and the image.

Comment: yes.. i try to do with css style: position:absolute and z-index:-1.

Comment: the image now is under my grid containter

Comment: i can swipe over the header and footer,

Comment: with internet explorer it works, but the with the other browsers do nothing

Answer (score -1):

Try attaching your events to something other than `document`, for example:

```
$( '[data-role="page"]' ).on( 'swipeleft', function( event ) {
   ...
} );
```